# Конкатенация строк

Tags: c++

Пишу курсовой по MFC. В нем использую MySQL. Что можно использовать для удобной конкатенации строк - надо постоянно из форм, вставлять в чаровскую строку (запрос) и передавать. Понял, что как PHP не получится) 
Что выбрать из такого обилия строчных типов? `CString, string, char *` или еще что?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Выбирай `string`, конкатенация делается так `str3 = str1 + str2`.

Comment: Без крайней необходимости в С++ используйте только std::string. Простой и безопасный способ.

Answer (score 3):

```
string s   = "Hello, ";
string s1  = "world!\n";
string sum = s + s1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `strcat` присоединяет к строке, переданной первым параметром, строку, переданную вторым параметром. В данном случае строки - это массивы элементов типа char. В C++ массивы не являются динамическими структурами, то есть не могут изменять свой размер во время выполнения программы. Поэтому в массиве (строке), переданном первым параметром в `strcat`, должно быть достаточно места, чтобы туда поместились обе строки. Объявляя строку так

```
char* slovo1  =  " proger ";
```

вы создаёте массив char'ов размером ровно в длину строки " proger " (плюс один элемент под нуль-терминатор). Если вы хотите сложить две строки, вам придётся выделить память под результат:

```
cahr* slovo = new char[strlen(slovo1) + strlen(slovo2) + 1];
strcat(slovo, slovo1);
strcat(slovo, slovo2);
printf(slovo);
```

Есть и другие способы. Например, с использованием класса stringstream:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << slovo1 << slovo2;
printf(ss.str().c_str());  // ну, или cout << ss;
Или используя класс string:

string slovo1 = " proger ";
string slovo2 = " riger ";
slovo1 = slovo1 + slovo2;
cout << slovo1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Класс лучше всего использовать естественно string т.к. это стандартный класс с++. В нём есть перегруженный оператор +=, который добавляет символы и метод append.

[class string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) - более подробная инфа

Ещё есть класс `System::String`, в нём конкатенация выполняется через знак сложения, как в ПХП, но этот класс работает только в Visual Studio.

Comment: Вообще-то и для стандартного string имеется перегруженный operator+, так что можно совершенно спокойно плюсовать несколько строк и даже string + char\* (или char\* + string)